# Why is my image in S3 being saved as characters(����94qgs��jX���z) instead of as an image?

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3, postman

I'm using angular and node in my front end and springboot in my back end. Using Postman to post images to S3, the image posts successfully, however, when using my web application, the image gets posted as a long string of characters/letters/symbols. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

````
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button mat-raised-button type="button" mat-button color="primary" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>```


.ts:

```import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component ({
    selector: 'upload-images',
    templateUrl: './upload-images.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-images.css']
})

export class UploadImagesComponent {
    selectedFile: File = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    onFileSelected(event) {
        this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    }

    onUpload() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file-0', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/storage/uploadFile', formData)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: How do you know your image is being correctly posted to S3 using postman ?

Comment: Because in my bucket I can open up the image and view it. Postman responds with it's unique URL. When I upload via my application, I can see it in my bucket, when clicked on it takes me to a page that says at the top "The image .... cannot be displayed because it contains errors." If I download it and open in a text editor, I get a long string of black diamonds with question marks among other characters. I am using VS Code and I notice that once I click upload, the long string of characters begins to run through my terminal I have node running on.

Comment: Have you tried changing the headers to include 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've tried using multipart/form-data